# Caffeine - How to set for each entity its own "expiration time"

Tags: caffeine

We used to use the guava cache and we want to change it to caffeine.

We want to set for each entity its own "expiration time", something like - put(K key, V value, long expiration_time).

I saw the 3 functions above and I wonder what exactly they are doing, if you can explain me the meaning ant the operations of each one of them it will be great.

For example, the return value of expireAfterCreate should be the duration we want for this entity from it's creation untill it's expiration? or something else?

I'm also wondering why we have the parameter "currentTime" in both expireAfterRead and expireAfterUpdate if we don't use it in the function?

When we used the guava cache we used the expireAfterAccess, what is the substitution for it in caffeine?

My last question is how can I set a default value for entities without a unique expiration time.

Thank you,

May

Answer (score 1):

> When we used the guava cache we used the expireAfterAccess, what is the substitution for it in caffeine?

We mirror the Guava API, so this is also available on the cache builder.

> My last question is how can I set a default value for entities without a unique expiration time.

Use `expireAfterAccess`, `expireAfterWrite`, or return a constant duration with `expireAfter(Expiry)`.

> I saw the 3 functions above and I wonder what exactly they are doing, if you can explain me the meaning ant the operations of each one of them it will be great.

`Expiry` is a callback interface where a single timestamp value is updated. The invoked method corresponds to the operation performed on the cache entry (created, updated, read). An update or read that should have no effect can return `currentDuration` to no-op.

> For example, the return value of expireAfterCreate should be the duration we want for this entity from it's creation untill it's expiration? or something else?

Yes. However if the `expireAfterUpdate` returns a custom value (something other than `currentDuration`), then that overrides the prior expiration duration.

> I'm also wondering why we have the parameter "currentTime" in both expireAfterRead and expireAfterUpdate if we don't use it in the function?

This can most often be ignored, but is provided if somehow useful. It is the current nano timestamp from the `Ticker` (not wall clock time).

> We want to set for each entity its own "expiration time", something like - put(K key, V value, long expiration_time).

The callback `Expiry` is required and generally recommended, because ideally entries are loaded through the cache to avoid stampedes (e.g. `LoadingCache`). A stampede is when multiple threads lookup the same entry, miss, load it, and overwrite each other putting it in. That wasted work rather than having only one thread perform the load and others wait for the results.

That said, this method is available under `Cache.policy().expiresVariably()`. Those configuration-specific methods are stashed in that area to offer more power when deemed necessary.

> Thank you,

You're very welcome.